# What does $_files array contain? How to reference it?

Tags: php

I'm a raw PHP beginner. Check out this sample upload script:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

Now, how to see exactly what values this built-in array contain? I cannot find such an info anywhere. Thanks for the time.

Comment: Have you tried googling `$_FILES`? This is the first result: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Yes I have. From PHP.NET: "An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method."
1. Judging by the way they access it in this code it looks like it is multidimensional array.
2. If it is, i just want to know how many arrays are there and what do they contain? This info is not included in the official PHP documentation ;/

Comment: I think you have to try searching a bit more. There are a lot of results about file upload, and even general debugging (print_r, var_dump etc.)

Comment: Scroll down the page on http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php and you'll see what it is meant to contain

Answer (score 2):

You mean `var_dump($_FILES)`? That tells you exactly what the array contains.

Comment: you will probably want to do `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_FILES,true).'</pre>'` to get it in a more easily readable way without having to view the source of the page